# ASP.NET CheckBox in ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, checkbox

So I have a list view and inside I have a checkbox and two radio button. The checkbox controlls where the radiobuttons are disabled or enabled.

As you can see I have it working for the first item in the list (items[0]) but how do I make it work for the rest of the rows in the list view?

Thanks

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView lv2 = ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("ListView2") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView;
            CheckBox cb = lv2.Items[0].FindControl("ChargedCB") as CheckBox;
            RadioButton acceptRB = lv2.Items[0].FindControl("AcceptedRB") as RadioButton;
            RadioButton disputedRB = lv2.Items[0].FindControl("DisputedRB") as RadioButton;

            if (cb.Checked == false)
            {
                acceptRB.Checked = false;
                disputedRB.Checked = false;

                acceptRB.Enabled = false;
                disputedRB.Enabled = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                acceptRB.Enabled = true;
                disputedRB.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: But here it appears you have listview1 and inside it there is lv2 on the first row and inside lv2 there is checkbox and 2 radio buttons per row ? So you want to do this foreach nested listview lv2 in listview1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int k = 0;k<ListView1.Items.Count;k++)
{
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView lv2 = ListView1.Items[k].FindControl("ListView2") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView;

for(int i = 0; i<lv2.Items.Count;i++)
    {
                    CheckBox cb = lv2.Items[i].FindControl("ChargedCB") as CheckBox;
                    RadioButton acceptRB = lv2.Items[i].FindControl("AcceptedRB") as RadioButton;
                    RadioButton disputedRB = lv2.Items[i].FindControl("DisputedRB") as RadioButton;

                    if (cb.Checked == false)
                    {
                        acceptRB.Checked = false;
                        disputedRB.Checked = false;

                        acceptRB.Enabled = false;
                        disputedRB.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        acceptRB.Enabled = true;
                        disputedRB.Enabled = true;
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. lv2 cannot be found in the second loop and .Length is also not recognised.

Comment: 1st, replace Length with Count !. You need to try a little bit :).

2nd: Please explain more your structure of your listviews ListView1 and ListView2, because i mentioned 2 ways, and each is for a different structure. do you have only one ListView2 or on each row of ListView1 you have a "ListView2" ?

Comment: I have a list view inside a list view. So for every row in listview1 there is a listview 2 row. Inside listview 2 there is the checkbox and radio buttons.

Comment: You need the 2nd method i described, i will remove the first 1. Please apply and update me if you get any exceptions with details :)